# Local notifications in MAC in QT project

Tags: objective-c, macos, qt, notifications

I´m trying to implement local notifications in a project made in QT, this is made through KNotifications, the current issue is with MACOS, the following code is the one being used:

```c
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions: (UNAuthorizationOptionAlert) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable per_error) {

    NSLog(@"PERMISSION: %d - %@", granted, per_error);
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = @"TEST TITLE";
    content.body = @"TEST BODY";
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.defaultSound;

    NSUUID *uuid = [NSUUID UUID];
    NSString *str = [uuid UUIDString];
    UNNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:1 repeats: NO];
    UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier: str content:content trigger:trigger];

    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable req_error) {
        NSLog(@"REQUEST LOG: %@", req_error);
    }];
}];
```

When I run the code in an empty native XCode application, everything works fine, but when I run it on the QT / KNotifications project I get the following

```
Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1 "Notifications are not allowed for this application"
```

I have checked and my test application appears right away on "Systems Preferences" but the other is not listed